# I can't associate private class members with a friendly function

Tags: c++, class, friend-function

I have a problem with linking a class-friendly function and its private variables. The training task consists in creating a program that encrypts and decrypts the entered text based on the key with a Vigener cipher. Please help me! (here is link to dropmefiles and archive, where program places.
*It's my first question in stackoverflow
https://dropmefiles.com/JZFJd
here there is code of declaration class with friendly-funcion ("Vigenere_square.h"):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


class Vigenere_square
{
private:
    const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    size_t size;
    char** array;

public:
    Vigenere_square();
    ~Vigenere_square();
    //friend void encode();
    //friend void decode();
    //friend void output();
    friend string encode_string(const string& text, const string& key, const Vigenere_square& vs);
    
};
```

and here code of "encode.cpp" file:

```
#include "encode.h"
using namespace std;
string encode_string(const string& text, const string& key, const Vigenere_square& vs)
{
    string text2, key2;
    while (key2.length() <= text.length())
    {
        key2 += key;
    }
    size_t row, column, k;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < text.length(); k++) 
    {
        size_t row = vs.ALPHABET.find(key2[k]);
        size_t column = vs.ALPHABET.find(text[k]);
        if (row < vs.size && column < vs.size) {
            text2 += vs.array[row][column];
        }
        else {
            text2 += text[k];
        }
    }
    return text2;
}
```

I'm just a student, but I really don't know what I have to learn or understand. There is a very stupid mistake, but I can't find it.

Comment: You haven't said what the error is: logical, compilation, linking.  If compilation or linking you need to include the full errors from the compiler/linker,  Please read [mcve] and if possible remove any unnecessary code; make sure the example sill reproduces the problem, online compilers like [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) are useful for this,

Comment: No one is going to download some files, if you want help make it as easy as possible by creating a [mcve].

Comment: The code you've shown compiles fine so what is the actual problem?

Comment: Did you ask "please"? Being friendly alone does not cut in the USA.

Comment: You have a class declaring a function as a `friend` in `Vigenere_square.h`.   You have a source file that defines that function, but does not `#include "Vigenere_square.h"` anywhere.     For a source file to make use of declarations in a header file, that source file must `#include` that header (possibly via another header).    A C++ compiler does not attempt to find declarations in headers - it relies on you to `#include` all headers in all source files as needed.

Comment: I don't see the need for `friend` here at all just make it a member function of your class. `std::string encode_string(const std::string& text, const std::string& key);` (and yes you  should not be using `using namespace std;`). The in your .cpp file you will have `std::string Vignere_square::string encode_string(const std::string& text, const std::string& key)` Also `char** array;` is typically a `std::vector<string> array;` in current C++ (to avoid memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing header inclusion. Instead of `#include "encode.h"`, use `#include "Vigenere_square.h"`.

Friend functions may not be necessity here, just use public member functions.

If you need to expose private members, you can use setter/getter.